# SSL Record Layer vs TLSv1.2 Record Layer

Tags: java, ssl, iis, jboss, windows-server-2012-r2

I have a java based application. It tries to connect a web server through HTTPS. But, it fails in very first step of hand shake. I took tcp trace. I also check connection via browser. Browser connects successfully, even java fails. I took its tcp trace too. I checked the difference. Even they both uses TLSv1.2, their "Client Hello" messages are different. Java one uses "SSL Record Layer", browser uses "TLSv1.2 Record Layer" for "Client Hello" message.

Here screenshots of tcp dumps.

java:

[image]

and, detailed message of package of java

[image]

and, browser

[image]

and, detailed message of package of brwoser

[image]

Some versions informations:

Java version is 8 (source application, working in 10.x.x.170) Java application is working in JBoss 6.4 (source application) Web application works under IIS (Windows Server 2012, working in 10.x.x.171)

Question: How can I force java application to use same protocol with browser (browser looks working).

Comment: The record layer is the same but only displayed differently.  See https://ask.wireshark.org/questions/29404/ssl-record-layer-vs-tls-record-layer for details. Which means your problem is a different one. It might be related to SNI which your Java client is not using, but this is just a guess.

Comment: See logs:  -Djavax.net.debug=all. Try activate all protocols: -Dhttps.protocols=SSLv2Hello,TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2,SSLv3. May be -Djdk.tls.client.protocols=SSLv2Hello,TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2,SSLv3